# VBA, LDAP - How to retrieve multiple values of an LDAP directory entry attribute using ADODB in VBA

Tags: vba, ldap, adodb

For the following LDAP entry:

```
ou=People
ou=Europe
o=organisation.com
unit=Department 123
attribute1 = value1
attribute2 = value2
attribute2 = value23
attribute2 = value123
```

I'm trying to retrieve the values for all three 'attribute2' attributes, by means of the ADODB object in VBA. This is the LDAP URL string I'm using:

```
"<LDAP://server.com:389/ou=People,ou=Europe,o=organisation.com>;(unit=*123);attribute2"
```

The resulting record only contains one of the attribute2 values though.

Is there a way to retreive the values for all three 'attribute2' attributes, without specifying any part of any of the 'attribute2' attribute values?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

The recordset that is returned by the ADO connection string that I used actually does return all multiple values of attributes that have multiple values...the field value in this case is simply an array.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).